# How much should I expect to pay for a boat fare from Ko Lanta to Phi Phi Island in Thailand?

Tags: fares, sea-travel, phuket, phi-phi

I'm traveling from Ko Lanta to Ko Phi Phi Island by boat.

How much should I pay for the trip?

It will be me and one other passenger. I want to avoid being overcharged.

Answer (score 3):

One site provides fares [here](http://www.gokohphiphi.com/schedule.html).

- Ferry Phi Phi to Lanta 2hr - 450THB (approx USD$13)
- Ferry Phi Phi to Lanta by Speedboat 1hr - 700THB (approx USD$20)

Seem reasonable fares for such a distance.